# ¿Por qué la solución es esta?

Tags: python, funciones, python-3.7

```
def tipo(operacion):
    print(f'The {operacion} has been completed ')
    
def run():

    print(tipo('division'))
    
run()
```

La solución que me da es el Print y debajo un '''None'''
Me gusatria saber porque sale '''None'''
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El retorno por defecto en cualquier función de Python es `None`, en tu caso:

```
def tipo(operacion):
    print(f'The {operacion} has been completed ')
```

`tipo()` no retorna explícitamente ningún valor, la función simplemente imprime una cadena, algo que se conoce como efecto colateral, por lo que el retorno será `None` y al hacer: `print(tipo('division'))` el print final será `None`. Tal vez lo que busques es que la función `tipo` sea la que retorne la cadena que ahora se imprime:

```
def tipo(operacion):
  return  f"The {operacion} has been completed"
    
def run():
  print(tipo('division'))
    
run()
```

Comment: oh!, Muchas gracias por la explicación lo he entendido